# embed quiz into html5 video - cue points in a rich customizable player

Tags: html, video, media-player, jwplayer, flowplayer

Coursera has these interactive questions in the middle of their video lecture

- how could I go about implementing this myself,
- or better yet, does this feature exist for public use somewhere?

[image: custom-track-mixing]

Furthermore, I'm trying to decide which HTML5 video player / platform to invest in and the key criteria would be feature-rich (so as to not reinvent the wheel / spend lots of time implementing video player features) as well as highly customizable (for those custom needs).

- I.e. which player should I use to get the quiz up,
- but in the near future I would also need to add the speed feature that Coursera has
- I need Closed Captions support
- and would like to overlay slides every now and then
- plus all the expected features of switching between different source resolutions (360p, 720p etc), it should work in IE, Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Android and iOS native browsers etc

### Candidates

- In terms of customizability and feature-set, [SublimeVideo](http://sublimevideo.net/modular-player) seems to come on top, but I don't know [when they will support subtitles](https://getsatisfaction.com/sublimevideo/topics/_upcoming_feature_subtitles_comments_suggestions).
- Haven't researched [Flowplayer](http://flowplayer.org/designer/) much, would that be better for my purposes?
- [Jwplayer](http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw-player/features/) is good for all the standard features, and includes subtitle support, but I haven't really seen any plug-ins, aesthetic skinning aside, deep customization does not really seem to be their focus / strength?
- Or [videojs](http://www.videojs.com/)
- Or something else yet ?

Comment: You might be able to do this with the JW Player's JavaScript API, and seek() - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28851/javascript-api-reference

Comment: Would like to see an actual example of this in any player. @Cel have you got it working out the way you wanted?

Comment: @EthanJWPlayer - please can you give me some insight on this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27032811/how-to-add-custom-cue-points-in-jw-player

Comment: We don't have a cuepoints API I'm afraid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flowplayer and Jwplayer are amazing players and you could do what you want, but in the free version you can't remove their branding. I try to stick to opensource projects you you don't worry about licenses.

I've done something similar as you need with [Mediaelementjs](http://mediaelementjs.com/). It supports all you need at the moment, and they will support the variable speed at some point on the future as announced in their website. However it has been like that for more than a year now since I started watching, so probably your "near future" is before their "coming soon".

I think your best free option will be Videojs. They also support all you need. For the variable speed there is [this plugin](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/220).

Basically you set up a listener in the `timeupdate` event, and when it reaches the point that you need, you attach the quiz html to overlay the video area.

Answer (score 3):

I have used flowplayer extensively. I'm just now starting to dive more into their new HTML5 version. The licensing for flowplayer is reasonable. It does have a plugin for doing subtitles and the cue point functionality works great. I also like that they have the Flash version that works well for fallback and I still use it for rtmp streaming.

I have built a video presenter with synchronized slides using the flash version which I'll be changing over to have an HTML5 version. I use it to produce speaker videos with Powerpoint presentations. Sometimes we have surveys (live) so I have also been planning to build in the option for a survey slide.

You can take a look at what I have built as an example here (it has some lose ends). [Example synchronized video slide presentation](http://www.ecropolis.com/wc/presenter.html) (I have no affiliation with Flowplayer. WebVideoDesk, *branded on the linked page*, is a service I am planning to launch someday.)

Comment: please let me know if you get a chance to release an HTML5 version :)