# How to add custom cue points in JW player

Tags: javascript, jwplayer, jwplayer6

Say I have an array of time in seconds.

```
var points = [5, 30, 50];
```

So when the jw player is initialized, I want to read this array and then place cue points[markers] on the timeline.

And once the seek bar reaches the cue point, I want to call a custom function that performs something.

The documentation of Jw is very plain but I found this - [Adding chapter markers](http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1407454-adding-chapter-markers)

I need something similar to this with full control on the cue points.

Is there any way to achieve this or should I use a custom control bar?

Comment: We don't have a Cuepoints API I'm afraid. You can use your own JS, though - http://www.jwplayer.com/labs/experiments/hot-spots/

Answer (score 3):

I implemented the same thing by pausing the video on certain points. When paused, the user can only resume the video by clicking on a link (the controls are removed when paused).

I have the following HTML where the player and the cue points HTML are placed:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5">
        <div id="myElement">Loading the player...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-7">
        <div id="on10seconds" class="hidden">
            <p>Show after 10 seconds. <a href="#" class="positionInfoLink" data-position="10">Continue...</a></p>
        </div>
        <div id="on25seconds" class="hidden">
            <p>Show after 25 seconds. <a href="#" class="positionInfoLink" data-position="25">Continue...</a></p>
        </div>
        <div id="on50seconds" class="hidden">
            <p>Show after 50 seconds. <a href="#" class="positionInfoLink" data-position="50">Continue...</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the following JavaScript:

```
var positions = [10, 25, 50];
var positionsSeen = [];

var player = jwplayer("myElement").setup({
    file: "/Content/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4"
});
player.onTime(jwPlayerOnTime);

function jwPlayerOnTime(onTimeInfo) {
    var currentPosition = onTimeInfo.position;
    for (var i = 0; i < positions.length; i++) {
        var position = positions[i];
        var isPositionSeen = positionsSeen.indexOf(position) != -1;
        // Within 2 seconds, so users can't skip to see the extra information displayed when pausing.
        var isOnOrPastPosition = currentPosition > position && currentPosition <= position + 2;

        if (isPositionSeen == false && isOnOrPastPosition) {
            positionsSeen.push(position);
            player.pause(true);
            // Disable the controls, so the video can only be resumed with the custom controls.
            player.setControls(false);
            $("#on" + position + "seconds").removeClass("hidden");
        }
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".positionInfoLink").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var position = $(this).data("position"); // 10, 25 or 50.
        $(this).parent().addClass("hidden");
        player.play(true);
        // Enable the controls, so the video can be paused manually again.
        player.setControls(true);
    });
});
```